# Table doesn´t show data in Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table

I have a front on Angular 14 and a backend in .net core, the table is not showing any data. I have tested the backend and the data is coming, in fact the console.log shows:

```
0: {idDetalle: 1, nombreArticulo: 'Balón', cantidadArticulo: 3, idPedido: 1, pedidos: null}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

ts code:

```
idPedido!: number;  
  detalles: IDetalles[] = [];       

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, public dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.idPedido = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.dataService.GetDetallePorIdPedido(this.idPedido).subscribe((data: IDetalles[])=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.detalles = data;               
    });          
  }
```

html code:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">   

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">        
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; padding: 10px; margin: 40px;">            
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">DETALLES</h5>                                          
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/nuevo-detalle']" routerLinkActive="active">Nuevo Detalle</a>              
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    

    <div *ngIf="detalles">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%; margin: 40px;">
                <thead class="thead-dark">                    
                    <th>Nombre del Artículo</th>
                    <th>Cantidad del Artículo</th>
                    <th>Id del Pedido</th>                    
                    <th style="width:100px;">Actions</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of detalles">
                        <td>{{item.NombreArticulo}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.CantidadArticulo}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.IdPedido}}</td>                            
                        <td><a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/editar-detalle', item.IdDetalle]" routerLinkActive="active">Editar</a></td>                                                
                        <!-- <td><button type="button" (click)="eliminarDetalle(item.IdDetalle)" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button></td>      -->
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Outside the if I put, just for testing, this is not a part of the final program:

```
{{detalles[0].NombreArticulo}}
```

And it shows: Cannot read properties of undefined

Something is happening.. its like the array is not getting filled with the data.

In postman

```
http://localhost:25390/api/GetDetallePorIdPedido/1
```

shows

```json
[
    {
        "idDetalle": 1,
        "nombreArticulo": "Balón",
        "cantidadArticulo": 3,
        "idPedido": 1,
        "pedidos": null
    }
]
```

Comment: {{detalles[0]?.NombreArticulo}}  nothing can be seen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to display the data before it has come back from the server. `*ngIf` checks for a truthy value and and empty array evaluates to `true`.

You could subscribe to an observable and that way you will only see the table data once it has returned from the server or the data gets updated.

```js
@Component({})
export class TableComponent {
  detalles = new Subject<IDetalles[]>();
  detalles$ = this.detalles.asObservable();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.idPedido = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.dataService.GetDetallePorIdPedido(this.idPedido)
      .subscribe((data: IDetalles[]) => this.detalles.next(data));          
  } 
}
```

Then we change the `*ngIf` to watch the observable:

```html
    <div *ngIf="detalles$ | async as data">
       <!-- The data is ready now! -->
       <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
         <!-- Your cells -->
       </tr>
       {{data[0] | json}}
    </div>
```

Also [as noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72755272/1778465), you are using the wrong case for your property name.

Comment: With your changes... still not working

Comment: Did you change `NombreArticulo` to `nombreArticulo`?

Comment: inside the td?  Property 'nombreArticulo' does not exist on type 'IDetalles'. Did you mean 'NombreArticulo'?

Comment: Your question shows that the server is returning `"nombreArticulo": "Balón",` where the `n` is lowercase, but in your html you are using an `N` instead. Also does it say what it is trying to read? Usually it says `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading: 'xxx')`

Comment: I understand now, I have changed the interface and the names as you have said, it is working, thanks @Get Off My Lawn

Answer (score 0):

Your console log shows the object with properties in camel case. But you are trying to access in template with Pascal case.

`item.NombreArticulo` -> `item.nombreArticulo`.

Comment: console.log(data[0]?.NombreArticulo); undefined

Comment: use console.log(data[0]?.nombreArticulo);